# looping through lines of a .txt file in C++

Tags: c++, parsing, iostream, iomanip

Total C++ beginner and as the title says, i'm trying to read a .txt file looping through line by line whilst performing a calculation on the data of the line before moving to the next line.

```
int main() {

ifstream in_file;
string name;
int kiloWatt{};
int amperage{};
int cores{3};
int voltage{480};
double powerFactor{0.8}; 
double efficiency{0.93};
double root{};

in_file.open("../test.txt");
if(!in_file){
    cerr <<"Problem opening file" << endl;
    return 1;
}
while (in_file >> name >> kiloWatt){
    root = sqrt(cores);
    amperage = (kiloWatt*1000)/(root*voltage*powerFactor*efficiency);

    cout << setw(10) << name
         << setw(10) << kiloWatt
         << setw(10) << amperage
         << setw(10) << root
         << endl;
}
in_file.close();
return 0;
```

}

this works however it closes the loop after the first line and so displays only one line.... anyone point me in the direction of why? Many thanks.

The txt file its referencing would look something like:

```
name1 23.5
name2 45.6
name3 234.8
```

Comment: `kiloWatt` should be a double.

Comment: well now i feel silly.  Ive been looking at this for hours. cheers mate!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`kiloWatt` is an int, so on the first line, it'll read `23`, see a non-integer character and stop. The next `name` will be `".5"`, and you'll try to read `"name2"` into `kiloWatt`, which will fail, since it's not a number--breaking your loop.

Change `kiloWatt` to be a double to fix this.